# I need to compare md5sum in makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, md5sum

i´ve tried all my ideas.
@if ( `md5sum foto.jpg` = `md5sum fot.jpg` );then echo "OK"; else "FAIL"; fi ;
If you have any idea please help me

Answer (score 0):

How about just comparing files, and skip all the fiddling with checksums.

```
@if cmp foto.jpg fot.jpg >/dev/null; then echo OK; else echo FAIL; exit 1; fi
```